# No se ejecuta la sentencia execute o execteUpdate para insertar un PDF

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente codigo, lo que intento es agragar un PDF a una base de datos. El problema es que ejecuto la instruccion en SQL y funciona, pero intento hacerlo con Java y no lo hace Es decir siempre regresa un false.

```
Conexion c = new Conexion();
Connection con= c.getConexion();

if(con!=null){   
    Statement st;
    st = con.createStatement();
    String insertar = "INSERT INTO [Documentos](Nombre,Documento) VALUES('FacturaJK9389234',(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\\Datos\\"+fileName+"', SINGLE_BLOB) as Pdf))"; 

    out.println("<br />" + insertar ); 
    try{
        st.execute(insertar);
        agregado=true;
        st.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        agregado=false; 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
out.println("<br />" + agregado);
c.cerrarConexion();
```

Comment: Te fijaste (debuggeando) si caes en el catch SQLException y de ser así que stacktrace contiene?

Comment: Si, me dio esto:
Excepcioncom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se puede realizar la carga masiva. El archivo "C:\Datos\Mario (1).pdf" no se puede abrir. Código de error del sistema operativo: 5(Acceso denegado.). 

Ya he agregado permisos de bulkadmin, y no se que mas hacer.
Continua dando el mismo error.

Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el error se debe a que estás asignándole un alias al subselect al momento de querer hacer el insert:

```
as 'PDF'
```

Saludos.

Comment: Ya se lo he quitado y me da el mismo error:
Excepcioncom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se puede realizar la carga masiva. El archivo "C:\Datos\Mario (1).pdf" no se puede abrir. Código de error del sistema operativo: 5(Acceso denegado.). 

Ya he dado permisos de nulkadmin ami usuario y no consigo ejecutar la instruccion en Java, ya que en SQLserver la ejecuta normal.

Answer (score 0):

Tu instruccion

```
st.execute(insertar);
```

siempre retornara false ; ya que execute retorna true si y solo si tu query es un select , para los demas casos (update,delete,insert) retornara false.

si quieres validar que tu query se ejecuto correctamente y se añadio el registro a la tabla debes probar con lo siguiente :

```
int filasAfectadas = st.executeUpdate(insertar);
```

El metodo executeUpdate() retorna la cantidad de filas afectadas,si es mayor a 0 se añadio el registro de forma correcta

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder, lo he intentado tambien con executeUpdate, pero da el mismo error. Excepcioncom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se puede realizar la carga masiva. El archivo "C:\Datos\Mario (1).pdf" no se puede abrir. Código de error del sistema operativo: 5(Acceso denegado.). 

ya he dado permisos de bulkadmin y no consigo aun ejecutar esa instruccion con Java.

Comment: Puede que la forma que estas probando no sea la mas indicada mira carga tu PDF en un File y pasa este a un byte array, posteriormente graba el byte array en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

para los que tengan el mismo problema esta pagina me ayudo:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024123251/http://geekswithblogs.net/mgarcia/archive/2009/10/03/restorecontainer_validatetargetforcreation.aspx)

si era algo de permisos, por ahora lo estoy probando en un ambiente de prueba, lo que no se, es, cuando ya este en productivo no se puede dejar con tanta inseguridad, pero a publicare si es que existe un error.
Gracias a todos